# Can I access graphql-context from a spring bean?

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql-spqr

We are using spqr graphQl with Spring. It works great and simplifies a lot, thanks for that!
Right now we are using a ResolverInterceptor for authorization: A JWT-Token is read from DefaultGlobalContext and validated. 
We are also able to determine the current username from this token.
So now my question is: Can I store this username in a spring bean? Is there any connection between spring beans and the context?
What we do at the moment is to inject the DefaultGlobalContext as a @GraphQLRootContext into every method of our @GraphQLApi and get the user this way. 
It would be nicer if we could just read it once, store it somewhere and have access in a spring managed service. 
Does anyone know how to do that?
Thanks in advance, 
Matthias

Comment: I'd use a central data store like redis to store the user and its JWT. But I'm not sure if there's a Java specific way.

Answer (score 3):

There's a few things you can do.

**1. Custom `ArgumentInjector`**

The simplest way (and the one I'd recommend) is wiring a custom `ArgumentInjector`. You can make it react to some annotation, or just by type. E.g.

```
@Query
public Book book(String id, @LoggedIn User user) {...}
```

And an injector like:

```
public UserInjector implement ArgumentInjector {
    @Override
    public Object getArgumentValue(ArgumentInjectorParams params) {
        ResolutionEnvironment env = params.getResolutionEnvironment();
        return extractUserFromRootContext(env.rootContext);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(AnnotatedType type, Parameter parameter) {
        //You can also check type.getType().equals(User.class), but IMHO explicit is always better
        return parameter != null && parameter.isAnnotationPresent(LoggedIn.class);
    }
}
```

**2. Custom `GraphQLExecutor` and a request-scoped bean**

Another way is to have a `@RequestScoped` bean that you inject both into your `GraphQLExecutor` and into your `@GraphQLApi` class.

```
@Component
//implements GraphQLServletExecutor
public class CustomGraphQLExecutor extends DefaultGraphQLExecutor {

    //This is @RequestScoped
    private UserHolder userHolder;

    @Autowired
    public CustomGraphQLExecutor(
            ServletContextFactory contextFactory,
            Optional<DataLoaderRegistryFactory> registryFactory,
            UserHolder userHolder) {

        super(contextFactory, registryFactory.orElse(null));
        this.userHolder = userHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> execute(GraphQL graphQL, GraphQLRequest graphQLRequest, NativeWebRequest nativeRequest) {
        userHolder.setUser(getUserFromTheRequest(nativeRequest));
        return super.execute(graphQL, graphQLRequest, nativeRequest);
    }
}

@Service
@GraphQLApi
public class BookService {

    @Autowired
    private UserHolder userHolder; //@RequestScoped

    @Query
    public Book book(String id) {
        //Access userHolder as needed
        ... 
    }
}
```

I do not like this approach as it creates an invisible dependency to the `ThreadLocal`. If at any point you start making your resolvers asynchronous (which is highly probable with graphql-java), you'll need specially wrapped thread pools or the things won't work at all. (Also, if you ever turn to WebFlux, it likely won't work at all, as graphql-java isn't Reactor-aware and can't propagate the context).

**3. Use Spring Security**

Since all you're doing is basic Spring Security stuff, just use the features it gives you. It has the same issues as the request-scoped bean approach, but you at least don't have to do anything yourself. Spring already gives you `SecurityContext` access from anywhere. And if you customize the controller class, you can also inject `Principal` / `Authentication` directly into the controller methods.